# Change USB device serial number (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have three USB cameras. I need to be able to identify them, however, they all have the same vendor & product ID, as well as a serial number. Can I change the serial number somehow to be able to identify them? Thanks

This is what I get from the 'usb-devices' command in Ubuntu

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=32e4 ProdID=4689 Rev=41.04
S:  Manufacturer=HD USB Camera
S:  Product=HD USB Camera
S:  SerialNumber=2020042001
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=87(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  16 Ivl=16ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
```

Comment: I think the product ID and serial number are hardcoded. (In the best of worlds, the manufacturer would create individual serial numbers.) Is there some writable media in the cameras (for example SD card)? Can you modify some setting, that can be seen via USB?